# Display time and Date in twig

Tags: php, html, twig

I have a application in which I have to display time and Date in which month has to be in String format. Can anyone tell me any working example because I tried to find on google but could not find out much. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should really try [reading the manual](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html):

```
{{ post.published_at|date("m/d/Y") }}
```